# Variable path import in react JS

Tags: reactjs, image, import, dynamic-import

I'm new to react and these days I'm doing a project in react JS. So, I needed to make a function like in the below code.
[image]

So, I needed to import like this. But it's returning a promise instead. So it's not working. Is there any way to import a bulk of image files without putting importing statements one by one? (I need to get a bulk of image files without importing one by one and import them easily) So is there any way to create dynamically importing functions like in this code to get a bulk of image files easily?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you found your answer?

Comment: No. I just imported them one by one after that.